# I want to install SASS on mac but it gives the below error

Tags: ruby, npm, sass

I am trying to install SASS on my mac but display the below errors i already installed node and npm

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall
>   access npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] { npm ERR!   stack:
>   "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'", npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!
>   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR! } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The
>   operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely
>   you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current
>   user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions
>   issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and
>   its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again
>   as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/mohammadullahasrar/.npm/_logs/2019-09-05T02_35_50_611Z-debug.log

To install sass successfully

Comment: What command did you run? Have you tried running the command with `sudo`?

Comment: Both : 1. npm install -g sass       2. gem install sass --user-install

Comment: @josephting  Once i updated the ruby and then i used : sudo npm install -g sass
/usr/local/bin/sass -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.js
+ sass@1.23.0-module.beta.1
updated 1 package in 1.152s

Comment: When i checked the SASS version it shows it:  sass -v
Could not find an option or flag "-v".

Usage: sass <input.scss> [output.css]
       sass <input.scss>:<output.css> <input/>:<output/> <dir/>

━━━ Input and Output ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
    --[no-]stdin               Read the stylesheet from stdin.
    --[no-]indented